# ERC725 adopting/extending ERC721 non fungibility attribute for unique decentralized identifier (DIDs)

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, erc725

Like the ERC20 standards, which is a great standard, I am imagining a future where there will be full of erc725 based token/identities. For decentralized identities to be unique, is there some way to adopt and leverage ERC721 for its non-fungible attributes?

Is there a possibility of ERC725 adopting/extending ERC721 non fungibility attribute for truly truly unique decentralized identifier (DIDs)?

Answer (score 0):

ERC721 by itself will not make a difference in creating a truly unique decentralized identifier. The only thing that can make an identity unique is consensus that it is unique. ERC725 is by itself not an identity, but a key management and proxy contract. With the addition of attestations via ERC735 you can build up an identity based on the strength and number of attestations and consensus about what they mean. Different parties may more or less trust the identity to be unique based on the attestations tied to it.

For example, if your country / state can reliably issue a claim that is tied to your ERC725 address then you could use that to prove you were a unique individual to most people. In order to verify that uniqueness parties that care about it need to verify the claims attached and make a judgement based on the claims. This would apply to ERC721 as well, you would need attestations tied to the ERC721 token for it to act as an identity.

Comment: Thanks! Specifically, how can consensus with one's identity be achieved through the use of ERC725/ERC735?

Comment: Ensuring unique decentralized identities is hard. One way might be through a web of trust, with identities attesting via ERC-735 as to the validity of others uniqueness in a social graph. Face to face validation would be ideal. Without it there is still the possibility of Sybil attacks. This can be mitigated to some extent by requiring bonds or deposits along with the attestation. The bonds might have time delays to reclaim them after invalidating the attestation. This would make it expensive to create Sybils, especially large networks of them.